# How to Optimize this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have 3 tables:

- CRSTasks (ID,parentID)
- CRSTaskReceivers (ID,tskID,receiverID)
- UserNames (id,name)

...relation between CRSTasks and CRSTaskReceivers one-to-many
between UserNames and CRSTaskReceivers one-to-one

```
tasks   
ID   parent  
1     null    
10     1      
50     1

taskReceivers  
id      taskID    receiverID  
1        1          4(john)  
1        10         2(mike)  
1        50         3(brand)
```

I need result like that:

```
taskid    Receivers
------------------- 
1           jone,mike,brand
```

ONLY FOR PARENT TASKS IT WILL CONCATE RECEIVERS

Comment: Do you want a single string of all the answers returned from this function?  What are you using that for?

Comment: First off, welcome to SO.  Your question is very unclear.  You can get better answers if you trim away the parts you understand, leaving only the core of what your question is.  That way someone who knows the answer to your question can quickly know what your question is.

Comment: @ramadan2050: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Thank u all, I Changed in The question, Hoping it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL Server 2005+:

---

```
SELECT t.id AS taskid,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ x.name
                FROM (SELECT COALESCE(pu.[ArabicName], aut.Name) AS name
                        FROM CRSTaskReceivers tr 
                        JOIN AD_USER_TBL aut ON aut.id = tr.receiverid
                   LEFT JOIN PORTAL_USERS pu ON pu.id = aut.id
                       WHERE tr.crstaskid = t.id
                         AND tr.receivertype = 1
                      UNION
                      SELECT agt.name
                        FROM CRSTaskReceiver tr
                        JOIN AD_GROUP_TBL sgt ON agt.id = tr.receiverid
                       WHERE tr.receivertype = 3
                         AND tr.crstaskid = t.id) x
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
  FROM CRSTasks t
```

Don't need the function.

Comment: I feel that u r near :)  I tried it but there is something wrong it only retrieve one name   e.g  1 john  2 sam  3 mike  where it is supposed to retrieve  1 jone,adam,pla...

Comment: ok ok, I have another thing may be it will help, the task table have a self join relationship, parentTask  Id:1 parent:null receiverID:10(john) 
Id:2 parent:1 receiverID:15(adam)
Id:3 parent:1 receiverID:7(mag)  
so result will be only fo parent tasks
so it will be   [1 -  John,adam,mag]

Comment: Updated cuz I missed the group name was being added.

Comment: Hi OMG Ponies,  Thank u for ur effort But it also take alot of time to excute the query

Answer (score 1):

Besides the odd string concatenation going on it sure looks like all that could be done in one query instead of four. It's perfectly fine to have more than one criteria in a join. Something along:

```
FROM   CRSTaskReceiver
   INNER JOIN CRSTask
        ON  CRSTaskReceiver.CRSTaskID = CRSTask.ID
   INNER JOIN CRS_BuiltinGroup
        ON  CRSTaskReceiver.ReceiverID = CRS_BuiltinGroup.ID AND CRSTaskReceiver.ReceiverType = 4
WHERE  CRSTask.ParentTask = @TaskID
```

Also the below part of the function seems to do absolutely nothing. What is it meant to do?

```
DECLARE @tmpLength INT
SET @tmpLength = 0
SET @tmpLength = LEN(@tmp)
IF @tmpLength > 0
BEGIN
    SET @tmp = SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, @tmpLength)
END
```